# Change template when TOTAL_FORMS = 0 - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

What I want to do is display a div depending on the number of forms:

```
<div id="form-nav">
    <div id="add-event">
        <input type="submit" name="add_event" value="Add Event">
    </div>
    {% if formset.TOTAL_FORMS == 0 %}
    <div id="save-next">
        <input type="submit" name="coding_form_next" value="Save without Event">
    </div>
    {% elif %}
    <div id="save-stay">
        <input type="submit" name="coding_form_save" value="Save new Events">
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected end of expression in if tag.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Change `{% elif %}` to `{% else %}`

The IF/ELSE structure of Django templates are

```
{% if condition_here %}
{% elif another_condition_here %}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if condition_here %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

and of course the simplest

```
 {% if condition_here %}
 {% endif %}
```

And [here's the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you also happen to know if I can access the TOTAL_FORMS value of the formset at all? Because the way I do it it always goes to the `else`...

Comment: I think you should be able to do it like this `formset.total_form_count`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can :)